# How can I close the right side of intelij idea maven run debug console split in two?

Tags: maven, debugging, intellij-idea, console

How can I close the right side of intelij idea maven run debug console split in two

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywpk8.png)

Comment: This question should be asked to your software provider rather then SO community.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide the left pane. There is a related request you can vote for: [IDEA-231652](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231652).